# Mentioning bibliography in "list of content page"

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing thesis and `\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=12pt]{book}` I am using. But after producing the .pdf file I don't see bibliography in the page of "list of content" as a heading as shown in the attached picture. please suggest how i can do that along with Appendix's?[image]

Here is the preamble:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
%\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=12pt]{book}
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} %Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
%\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt
%\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
%%%%%%%Bibliography
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{51}
S. L. Glashow, "partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions," Nucl. Phys., vol. 22,pp. 579-588, 1961.
\end{thebibliography}
```

I wrote bibliography in this way:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{1} Technical Design Report.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Your write-up isn't very clear. For sure, the screenshot you posted *does* include an entry to the "Bibliography" chapter. Please clarify.

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to use `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`.

Comment: You should read about [bibliographies and citations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies). The way you are doing it is completely unsuited for a thesis. It also has nothing to do with `natbib`, so i am removing the tag.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @ Johannes_B 2: still not.

Comment: @Mico: I have modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective still isn't entirely clear to be, but I think you want a line-item entry in the Table of Contents pointing to the unnumbered, chapter-level entry called "Bibliography". If this interpretation is correct, the following modified and augmented form of your code may be of relevance to you.

Some additional comments. First, note that you should *not* be loading the `subfigure` package -- it's deprecated, and it's been deprecated for several years already. Instead, load either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package. Second, the `fncychap` package seems to be incompatible with one or more of the other packages you load. Third, do ask yourself if you really need to load all of those packages; I strongly suspect that you do not. Last but not least, please observe that the `hyperref` package should be loaded *last*.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
%%\usepackage{subfigure}  %% deprecated! don't use it!
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % do you really need this package?
\usepackage{textcomp} % do you really need this package?

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\setlength{\parindent}{0in} % if you set '\parindent' to zero, 
   % you should set '\parskip' to a non-zero length

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno} % do you really need this package?
\usepackage{pdflscape}

%\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
% \bibliographystyle{...} %% choose a suitable bib style

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % <-- per Johannes B's suggestion

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package LAST
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue,
            linktocpage,  % optional
           }

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Hello, World}
\section{In the beginning}

A numeric-style citation call-out: \cite{51}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{51}
S. L. Glashow, ``Partial symmetries of weak interactions,'' \emph{Nucl.\ Phys.}, vol.\ 22, pp.\ 579--588, 1961.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```